# Añadir contacto usando código QR

Tags: qrcode

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web cuyo propósito es escanear códigos QR y realizar acciones según la información de su contenido. Me gustaría saber cómo, mediante un código QR, se podría añadir un contacto en un teléfono (se que se puede ya que algunas tarjetas de clientes lo hacen).
Debería ser el QR el que le 'dice' al teléfono que es un contacto? O la aplicación que escanea los códigos detecta lo qué es un contacto de lo qué no?

Sé que la pregunta es muy abierta pero alguien sabría darme una posible solución?

Actualmente uso una librería gratuita de javascript que se llama  [**kjua**](https://larsjung.de/kjua/) para generar y editar los códigos QR

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Los códigos QR simplemente son atajos que te mandan a un enlace, en dicho enlace deberás tener un archivo "Vcard" a descargar, con eso el teléfono entiende que es un contacto. Aquí te dejo un punto de partida: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-a-vcard-for-a-website éxitos con el desarrollo y su implementación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay webs que diréctamente rellenas un formulario con la información de contacto que suele tener una vcard, y después te genera el QR. Se esta manera cuando se escanea mediante un smartphone se añade directamente a contactos. Un ejemplo de una web que te lo genera es el siguiente:

http://es.qrcode-pro.com/ pero hay mil de estos...

Otra posibilidad para no tener que rellenar los datos es exportar tu vcard de tu esmartphone si lo tienes creado, después lo abres con un editor de código y lo pegas en una web al estilo del anterior indicado que al pegar el código te genera el QR con información vcard para poder añadir diréctamente a la lista de contactos de los smartphone.

Saludos amigo.